# Почему не работает событие window.onload !?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос банален... Почему ничего не происходит ?

```
window.onload = function(){ 
 alert("hello world");
}
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/oyAP/1/edit  работает!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Видно что-то у вас не прогружаются, это легко увидеть используя Chrome/DevTool/Newtwork, FF/FireBug/Newtwork, IE8+/DevTool/Newtwork

[image: img]

1. Синяя полоска — [`DOMContentLoaded`](http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)
2. Красная — `onLoad`

P.S. Лучше избегать использование `onLoad;`

Comment: А как в таком случае вызывать функцию при загрузке страницы? Я сейчас пользовался событием в <body onLoad="#">, а возможно как то по другому вызывать функцию ?

Comment: Использовать событие DOMContentLoaded — http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Answer (score 1):

DOMContentLoaded - наилучший вариант.
в большинстве случаев работает даже если у вас есть проблемы с подгрузкой различных версий jquery